# Compare TSV files and mark true/false

Tags: bash, shell

I have two TSV files and I'm trying to use the second one to compare with the first one and see if the key exists; and if it does, mark it in the first table as true. For example

File 1:

```
K1 Va1 Va2 Va3 Va4 Va5  
K2 Vb1 Vb2 Vb3 Vb4 Vb5 
K3 Vc1 Vc2 Vc3 Vc4 Vc5
```

File 2:

```
K1
K3
```

Trying to output:

```
K1 Va1 Va2 Va3 Va4 Va5 True
K2 Vb1 Vb2 Vb3 Vb4 Vb5 False
K3 Vc1 Vc2 Vc3 Vc4 Vc5 True
```

Right now, I'm trying to join the second file with all True's, so that its K1 - True, K3 - True. Then I'm trying to join that with the first file and marking empty boxes with False. But I feel like this is a terrible way to do it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily solved using `awk`

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0];next};{$NF = $NF OFS ($1 in a? "True": "False"); print}' file2 file1
```

Iterate through `file2` and store each key in an array `a`. Next, iterate through `file1`, modifying the last column by tacking on either `True` or a `False` depending on whether the key from field 1 is found in array `a` or not followed by printing the line. This produces:

```
K1 Va1 Va2 Va3 Va4 Va5 True
K2 Vb1 Vb2 Vb3 Vb4 Vb5 False
K3 Vc1 Vc2 Vc3 Vc4 Vc5 True
```

Comment: Yup, this did it! Thank you! That was a lot more straightforward than the way I was doing it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{key[$1];next}$1 in key{printf "%s - True\n",$1}' file2 file1 >tmpfile && mv tmpfile file2
```

should do it.

**Output**

```
$ cat file2
K1 - True
K3 - True
```